# How to convert caffe model and weight to pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, caffe

Hello I need help converting weight and model of caffe to pytorch. I have tried using the github that most other post suggest to use this [github](https://github.com/marvis/pytorch-caffe) but when I used it, I encounter a lot of problem since it used python 2 and currently I am using python 3. I have already tried to remove some layer that the github doesn't cover, manually change old syntax to the new syntax but the last error reference to nn module from pytorch and I have no idea to fix that.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "caffe2pytorch.py", line 30, in <module>
    pytorch_blobs, pytorch_models = forward_pytorch(protofile, weightfile)
  File "caffe2pytorch.py", line 17, in forward_pytorch
    net = caffenet.CaffeNet(protofile)
  File "/home/cgal/reference/SfSNet/caffe2pytorch/caffenet.py", line 384, in __init__
    self.add_module(name, model)
  File "/home/cgal/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 186, in add_module
    raise KeyError("module name can't contain \".\"")
KeyError: 'module name can\'t contain "."'
```

So is there any suggestion on how to convert caffe weight and model to pytorch?

This is the caffe model that I want to convert [download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tEM_c45b6h-uREZ5ooNd9pLPlUzR1VE6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried ONNX? which is often used to convert between frameworks?

Comment: it may help you - [see](https://github.com/vadimkantorov/caffemodel2pytorch)

Comment: So I need to convert it to onnx first then pytorch?